# Where can I get OCD Division of a state's district_court based on an address?

Tags: usa, api, geocoding, district

I am unable to find an API that will return the district_court OCD division for an address. I have tried the Google Civic Info API (specifically https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/civicinfo/v2/civicinfo.representatives.representativeInfoByAddress) and look through the Open States API.

I'm trying to do this for North Carolina addresses. Here is the map of current districts: http://www.nccourts.org/Courts/Trial/District/Documents/DistrictCourtmap15.pdf

Comment: running the address for Jennette's Pier, google civic api returns " "ocd-division/country:us/state:nc/cd:3": {
   "name": "North Carolina's 3rd congressional district"," you can't use that to determine the court? although...looking at your map i see 3a and 3b, but no 3 in nc.

Comment: address for Jennette's Pier: 7223 S Virginia Dare Trail, Nags Head, NC 27959

Comment: The congressional districts are different from the judicial districts in NC.

Comment: ha. my bad for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

on the fly solution:
This map of [North Carolina Trial Courts](http://www.nccourts.org/County/Default.asp) provides links to county pages that have the judicial district number. I would write a quick script to crawl that and get jd number linked to a county name. Then in the Google Civic API, after making a call, you can pull out the county name of said call response, and match to that.

EDIT:
Here's a gist with the JSON and the Python script I cobbled together. Note: I had to edit JSON manually to get this exact structure, but the script does output valid JSON.
Also uploaded Congressional District by County, and Congressional District by Place JSON files.
https://gist.github.com/jalbertbowden/b2323725ad362412ba5cd23a01d46cdd

Comment: Interesting solution! I have no idea how to write a script to crawl pages though.